# Присвоить многомерному массиву данные, извлеченные из БД

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных

Возникла такая проблема. Не могу понять как данные, извлеченные из БД, присвоить трехмерному массиву. Данные выводятся правильно, а вот с присвоением возникает проблема.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($weather); $i++) {

    for($j = 0; $j < count($stations); $j++) {

        if ($date1 < $date2) {
            $req = mysql_query("SELECT $weather[$i] FROM main WHERE date <= '$date2' AND date >= '$date1' AND stat_num = '$stations[$j]' ORDER BY date");
        }
        else if ($date1 > $date2) {
            $req = mysql_query("SELECT $weather[$i] FROM main WHERE date >= '$date2' AND date <= '$date1' AND stat_num = '$stations[$j]' ORDER BY date");
        }
        else {
            $req = mysql_query("SELECT $weather[$i] FROM main WHERE date = '$date1' AND stat_num = '$stations[$j]'");
        }

        while($k = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
            //$out[$i][$j][$k] = $k[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не используйте устаревшее расширение mysql, используйте PDO в нем есть в том числе и готовые функции  читающие все строки в массив. И кроме того не надо делать вложенные циклы по  чтению БД, надо сделать один запрос, который выберет все данные и потом их скопом прочитать и разложить как удобно

Comment: И почему вы кстати читаете по одной колонке беря их названия из массива, точно стоит читать сразу все колонки за один проход ...

Comment: Просто я не знаю как правильно сделать. Если я всё скопом прочитаю, то потом разбивать запарюсь. Так-то я понимаю, что такого делать нельзя.

Comment: а что не так с разбиением. колонки можно задать в нужном порядке и они уже будут в читаемом массиве в нужном порядке, так что можно будет присваивать целый массив. И в конце колонка stat_num по содержимому которой вы определите в какой элемент массива эту строку положить

Comment: Извините, если отвлекаю. Сегодня руки дошли до PDO. Сделал примерно так, как вы подсказывали. Но теперь проблема в том, чтобы правильно присвоить извлеченные данные массиву (в том виде, в котором мне нужно). Если не затруднит, посмотрите пожалуйста эту тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646294

Answer (score 0):

Функция $array[] может использоваться для добавления одного элемента в массив.
Для добавления нескольких элементов (в конец массива) служит функция array_push.
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php

Логики кода тут не касаюсь, отмечу лишь, что расширение mysql устарело, используйте PDO и будет счастье всем.