# Присвоить извлеченные из БД данные трехмерному массиву

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Не могу сообразить, как присвоить, извлеченные из бд данные присвоить трехмерному массиву.

```
if ($date1 < $date2) {
    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT $w FROM main WHERE date <= '$date2' AND date >= '$date1' AND stat_num = $s ORDER BY date");
}
else if ($date1 > $date2) {
    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT $w FROM main WHERE date >= '$date2' AND date <= '$date1' AND stat_num = $s ORDER BY date");
}
else {
    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT $w FROM main WHERE date = '$date1' AND stat_num = $s");
}

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    foreach ($row as $r) {
        echo $r . " ";
    }
}
```

$w - это типы погоды (например ск.ветра, температура и т.д.), а $s - номера станций, с которых получены данные о погоде. Массив нужен будет для того, чтобы выводить несколько графиков с различными типами погоды. В каждом графике будут данные с разных станций (т.е. несколько кривых на одном графике). Я предполагаю, что выглядеть массив должен примерно так: arr[тип_погоды][станция][ед_данных]. Вот только я сильно туплю и не знаю, как это сделать.

Примерный массив:

```
Array
(
    [температура] => Array
        (
            [станция1] => Array
                (
                    [дата1] => -6.5
                    [дата2] => -8.8
                    [дата3] => -2.1
                )

            [станция2] => Array
                (
                    [дата1] => 7.2
                    [дата2] => 2.3
                    [дата3] => 3.5
                )

        )

    [точка_росы] => Array
        (
            [станция1] => Array
                (
                    [дата1] => 11.1
                    [дата2] => 10
                    [дата3] => 12.1
                )

            [станция2] => Array
                (
                    [дата1] => 10.4
                    [дата2] => 9
                    [дата3] => 13.3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то надо `$arr[$w][$s][] = $r` (вместо echo)

Comment: Так не получится. $w и $s это строки, преобразованные из массивов. И даже если брать массив, тоже не то.

Comment: В в БД нет числовых ИД типов погоды? Может, лучше по ним... Хотя, и по строкам РНР должен работать...

Comment: Приведите примерный массив получаемых данных

Comment: Добавил в основное описание

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вообще вам посоветовал переделать всю логику. Для начала не храните все в одной таблице. Сделайте таблицу `Stations` (напр. id, name, description), таблицу `TypeWeathes` (напр. id, type, unit) и таблицу `Readings` (напр. id, id_station, id_type, date, value). Далее по определённым параметрам (напр. дате) дёргайте таблицу показаний и через join (если необходимо) тяните дополнительные данные о типах и станциях. В итоге обрабатывайте ответ как вам необходимо. Например:

`$sql = 'SELECT Readings.date as date, Readings.value as value, Stations.name as st_name
FROM Readings
INNER JOIN Stations
ON Readings.id_station=Stations.id';`

```
foreach ($rows->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['date'] . "\t";
    print $row['value'] . "\t";
    print $row['st_name'] . "\n";
}
```

**P.S.** Важен был посыл и немного разъяснений, работоспособность кода не гарантирую, т.к. не тестировал, но думаю логика понятна, в случае ошибки прошу исправить на рабочий пример!

Comment: Данные по станциям (название, координаты и т.п.) и так хранятся в отдельной таблице. Зачем записывать тип погоды с единицами измерения в отдельную таблицу не совсем понимаю, к тому же они могут изменяться в зависимости от того, что записано в других столбцах таблицы. Например, скорость ветра может измеряться как в м/с, так и узлах (зависит от одного из столбцов). За наводку спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Дополнение к прошлому сообщению. Если переделывать таблицы в БД так, как вы говорите, то придется переделывать все к/с приложение (этот кусок кода - маленькая его часть, единственная с которой возникли трудности), а на это может уйти много времени.

Comment: Я написал своё мнение и как реализовал бы я. Я не знаю всего вашего приложения и тонкостей, а лишь только отталкивался от приведенного кусочка